# Set $\{x | f(x) = \infty\}$ is of measure 0.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a measurable function $f$ and $ \int f < \infty$ . We want to show that  $\{x | f(x) = \infty\}$ is of measure 0. My attempt was the following: we can define the set $A = \{x | f(x) = \infty \}$ and we can define simple functions $\phi_n = n \chi_A$ where $\chi$ is the indicator function. Then, we see that $\phi_n \leq f$ $\forall n \geq 1$ and so we have that $\int \phi_n \leq \int f$ which implies that $n\chi_A \leq \int f$. From this point I don't know what to do or how to proceed. Is the process above a good one? How could I continue or can anyone give me another hint on how to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: I think the result should follow from your construction by contradiction.

Comment: Hint : $\mu(\{x | f(x) = \infty\}) = \mu(\cap_n\{ x | f(x) \geq n\})  = \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(\{f \geq n\})$  (Why?). Now use Markov's inequality (measure theory version) to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your proof: ($\mu$ is a measure)

$n\mu(A) \leq \int f$ and $ \int f < \infty$. Let $ \int f =a$. Then, $\forall n$ we have,
$n \mu(A) \leq a$ . Hence,
$\mu(A) \leq a/n$.
So, letting $n$ tends to $\infty$, we get,
$\mu(A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely already shown the basic properties of integrals. Specifically $f$ is integrable iff $|f|$ is integrable, and that integrals are linear. So a proof by contradiction would be:

$$\int |f|d\mu=\int_{|f|=\infty}|f|+\int_{|f|<\infty}|f|\geq \infty$$.